# Обособление двойным тире (Separation by double dashes)

Tags: пунктуация

Надо ли использовать двойное тире в следующем предложении для обособления?

> В асинхронном варианте выбор сгенерировать исключение или нет
>   оставлен на усмотрение программиста.

Т.е. будет ли такая конструкция верной?

> В асинхронном варианте выбор — сгенерировать исключение или нет —
>   оставлен на усмотрение программиста.

---

Should I use double dashes to separate explanation in the following sentence?

> В асинхронном варианте выбор сгенерировать исключение или нет  оставлен на усмотрение программиста.

Like so:

> В асинхронном варианте выбор — сгенерировать исключение или нет —
>       оставлен на усмотрение программиста.

Comment: По-моему, так делать можно, но только в том случае, если про этот выбор уже говорилось. По большому счету обособление двойным тире работает так же как скобки — выделяет _необязательное_ пояснение.

Comment: @Alissa спасибо за ответ!) да, ранее в контексте про этот выбор идет речь.

Comment: Вообще без каких-либо знаков препинания понять ваше предложение затруднительно, т. е. там точно должно стоять что-то парное, но вот что именно — тире, скобки или запятые — этого я определить не возьмусь. Да и контекста маловато. В текст какого рода входит это предложение? Инструкция пользователя? Учебник? Теоретическая статья?

Comment: @YellowSky да, я тоже чувствую, что его надо обособить. Однако школьные правила позабылись, поэтому не могу догадаться чем именнно) 

Это скорее инструкция. Вот полный абзац:

"Первый пример выглядит проще чем второй, но он имеет один недостаток: вторая строка **блокирует** исполнение любого нижеследующего кода, до тех пор, пока весь file.md не будет считан. Обратите внимание, если синхронная версия кода сгенерирует исключение, его нужно обработать, иначе процесс Node.js "упадёт". В асинхронном варианте выбор — сгенерировать исключение или нет — оставлен на усмотрение программиста."

Comment: Обычно тире заменяет какое-либо пропущенное слово. В данном случае: «В асинхронном варианте выбор  (того,) сгенерировать исключение или нет (, будет) оставлен на усмотрение программиста». ИМХО, обособление двойным тире более наглядно и более удобочитаемо, чем запятыми.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пунктуация очень часто вещь интонационная, это одна из причин её появления в принципе.

Сравните фразы. Просто прочтите их и послушайте, как они звучат в вашей голове:

> Выбор идти в институт или нет предстоит сделать каждому одиннадцатикласснику.

и

> Выбор — идти в институт или нет — предстоит сделать каждому одиннадцатикласснику.

Я бьюсь об заклад, что вторая прозвучит так, как будто кто-то произносит её в телерепортаже. Этаким поставленным дикторским голосом.

И первый вариант и второй правомерны, первый более частый.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Это не похоже на
[вставную конструкцию](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/).
Похоже на
[уточнение](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/),
но я лично использовал бы запятые.